# Remove application from memory

Tags: qt, qt4

I am trying to close an application

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "battle.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    battle w;
    int x = 14;
    if(x == 1)
    {
    w.show();
    }
    else if(x!=1)
    {
    qApp->exit(0);
    //Remove application from memory...
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

but if i go to windows processes,it is still there.What is the best way to remove the application from memory?.

Comment: This code makes no sense, nor would it ever compile. Please post actual code demonstrating the problem you are having. Hint: Once you give over control to the Qt mainloop, you have the exit from *inside* the application,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call a.exec() after you call qApp->exit(0).

Answer (score 0):

What's inside battle.h? If you start a thread in the battle class, and closing the window does not stop it, then the process will remain in the task list even if you close the window.